# Is it possible to drive LEDs using CCFL inverters?

Tags: led-driver, fluorescent-lamp, ballast, ccfl

I have a Tektronix oscilloscope with a CCFL backlit LCD. The CCFL tube is toast and rather than replace it with another one that will fail, I figured I would use the opportunity to replace it with a more modern LED backlight. The assembly part is straightforward, but the electronics is proving difficult.

The CCFL inverter is unfortunately integrated into the main board, so it's not swappable with an LED driver board. I could tap off one of the power rails, but I was wondering if there's an a less invasive solution. For home lighting, there are LED T8 tubes which can wired to either the existing Fluorescent ballast or directly to AC mains, such as the [Philips FlexFit (Hybrid UL Type A+B)](https://www.assets.signify.com/is/content/Signify/Assets/philips-lighting/united-states/20230914-instantfit-download-pdf.pdf). Is there such a circuit available for CCFLs?

Comment: Just from memory (and nothing to do with your specific CFL driver) they can yield on the order of about 60 mA RMS. Thereabouts. You'll have to test your unit to get a number, though. Also to get its voltage when loaded. But perhaps so, with some thought applied? Do an I-V curve experiment and log the data in your logbook. Then tell us what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a link.  Yes - I know that link-only answers are frowned upon.  However, I will flesh this out in just a short while.
[Tektronix THS720 Backlight modification with dropin replacement LED Controller](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/testgear/tektronix-ths7xxx-scope-ccfl-controller-drop-in-replacement-for-led-conversion/)

Bottom line: the link leads to an article describing the technique used to replace a CCFL lamp with LED.

The website is: EEVblog Electronics Community Forum

Comment: Are you related to the founders of the drug store chain?

Comment: Sorry - no relation as far as I know.